# Possibility of Using Quantum Teleportation Technology To Give People Telepathy

Tags: internal-consistency, technology, teleportation, quantum, telepathy

After reading about physicists achieving 'teleportation'of [subatomic particles using quantum teleportation](https://www.sciencealert.com/scientists-manage-quantum-teleportation-between-computer-chips-for-the-first-time). It made me consider having a story where a technology advanced, futuristic society using technology to teleport thoughts or ideas into each other's heads and using quantum teleportation to make this possible over extreme distances. This is done with an implant connected to the central nervous system and is the size of a business card. So the device is not too intrusive.

Is there any way to use quantum teleportation in order to create a form of electronic-based telepathy that is at least theoretically feasible based on current science, and if there is a way, how could you describe the device that allows for telepathy in a way that seems possible to develop?

Comment: Well, currently we don't really know how thoughts work, so I'd say no.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding, TylerMc, you have effectively your own question by proposing quantum teleportation (QT). QT has severe limitations. Thoughts could be exchanged between specific persons. Only those you share entangled states & they would be soon used up. Constant resupply of entangled states would be essential.

Comment: @a4android `you have effectively your own question by proposing quantum teleportation` Ummm... have effectively? I don't even. :)

Comment: [Quantum Teleportation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_teleportation#Non-technical_summary) still requires a classical information channel. At best, QT can be used for eavesdrop-proof the comunication between the two ends.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi Too bad it doesn't work against jamming. Oppss. Your QT is now jammed because someone keeps trying to see your thoughts!!!

Comment: @TravisWells "the (QT-)internet interprets jamming as damage and routes around it". See? no need for futuristic solutions :grin:

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi AI created by a future hyperpower and goes to cyberwar and jams all routes.

Comment: @TravisWells meh. [Skynet/AI is a crackpot](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AIIsACrapshoot) trope.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi So was the idea that one bomb can destroy a city 120 years ago.

Comment: @TravisWells don't get me wrong, I'm not saying it's hard to attack it. On the contrary, it's so easy that you don't need anything spectacular or original/extraordinary (not seen today) to make it happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Sure, but you might as well use the internet instead.**

If you have chips that can convert thoughts into electromagnetic signals, then you've already done the hard part. No need to complicate things by trying to encode that information into quantum states - just encrypt it and send it over Wi-fi. Or if your recipient is very far away, like light-years away, just send it to a radio terminal that beams your thoughts toward them through space.

The main issue with using quantum teleportation instead is that you can't just transmit the quantum data by itself. You actually have to send some signal to the receiver chip to tell it how to build the teleported matter at the other end. So effectively, any quantum processes happening here are redundant.

Forgive me for speculating, but there are only a few reasons I can think of that someone might want to use quantum teleportation in place of electromagnetic waves, and all of them are myths.

- Myth 1: Quantum teleportation is more secure.

This is the most plausible explanation, but even in a society with quantum computers, most quantum researchers would tell you that there are still probably ways to encrypt information sent online without quantum computers being able to unscramble it (i.e. elliptic curve cryptography).

- Myth 2: Quantum mechanics has something to do with consciousness.

I don't know where people get this from, but there's apparently an idea that thought is somehow a quantum phenomenon. Maybe you thought that this would make quantum states a good medium for transferring thoughts? All I can say is, based on our current understanding of neuroscience, this is not true at all. Neurons can be explained perfectly well in terms of classical electrons in a series of charge gates.

Of course, any way of recording and transmitting thoughts is pure sci-fi, so you could just declare that you need a quantum computer to do it. But I'd recommend against it, since it's difficult to write a sci-fi topic well if you don't know the science behind it.

- Myth 3: Quantum teleportation is faster

Again, just speculating, but if the reason you're using teleportation is to send thoughts across space instantaneously, then unfortunately, it won't work. Like I said before, quantum teleportation requires a second, non-quantum signal to complete the information transfer, so it can never transmit information faster than the speed of light.

If you're still dead-set on using quantum teleportation, my only response would be that both thought-transfer and quantum teleportation are technologies far ahead of our current time, so for all we know now, the chips you're describing are possible. However, I hope that my explanation above has convinced you that the element of quantum teleportation doesn't need to be there. As someone somewhat knowledgeable on the subject, its inclusion would have me scratching my head and wondering why conventional electronics weren't used instead.

Comment: Oppss. Hackers can now send signals to your brain shutting down your heart!! I don't think its wise to connect vital organs to the internet.

Comment: `Myth 2: QM has something to do with consciousness. I don't know where people get this from` you can blame the physics guys [who think they master biology too](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_mind). A special case of [Dunning–Kruger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning–Kruger_effect). Or maybe they are somehow right and we're "Dunning–Kruger"-ed?

Comment: Myth 2: They abuse the way quantum experiments "require" an observer. Mystics twist this to mean that our consciousness can change the fabric of the universe and therefore mind over matter is true and now every bullshit thing they do is justified because they control the quantum better than others.

Comment: Ordinary AES encryption is already impervious to quantum computers; all you need is move to AES-256 instead of AES-128. (Quantum computer, when and if they will become available, can do only a very small set of things really really faster than classical computers. Brute forcing AES is not one of them.)